# Датасет Sql запросов

Tags: sql

Я ищу датасет с sql запросами. В датасете запросы должны быть сгруппированы  по схожести например:

1. QUERY: `SELECT * from table_1 WHERE A>10`;
2. SIMILAR: `SELECT * from table_1 WHERE A>11`;
3. SIMILAR: `SELECT a,b,c from table_1 WHERE A>10`;
4. QUERY `SELECT DISITNCT a,b,c from table_1,table_2 WHERE a=b; SIMILAR`:
5. QUERY `SELECT DISITNCT a,b,c,d from table_1,table_2 WHERE a=b`;

Я нашел вот такой [датасет](https://github.com/UBOdin/EttuBench/tree/master/SQLFeatureExtraction/data) но он слишком маленький для моих нужд

Comment: Может быть вам просто сгенерировать его? Одних только `select * from table_1 where a > ...` можно сделать 4294967295 штук, например :-) Что за нужды у вас?

Comment: можно взять long и пойти дальше

Comment: @ЕгорБанин сильная идея, но мне нужны разнообразные запросы, все продумывать очень долго.  :)

Comment: @ИванГладуш окей, можно попарсить github (https://developer.github.com/v3/search/) делая поиск типа "select extension:sql" и собрать свой датасет.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин это будет датасет сырых данных мне нужно уже сгруппированных

Comment: Если такие датасеты и существуют, то боюсь в каждом источнике принципы группировки будут разными. Общего понятия "схожести" не существует. Есть всякие вещи типа расстояния Левинштейна, вас именно такая схожесть интересует ?

Comment: @Mike Левинштейна это хорошо, но хотелось бы что-то более точное

Comment: Что может быть точнее Левнштейна, когда дело касается просто текста

Comment: @Mike мы же про SQL говорили, SQL чутка больше чем текст

Comment: А чем он в ключе вашего вопроса отличается от текста ? вы пишите "схожесть", но не поясняете чем именно схожи приведенные вами примеры. Я кроме того, что их тексты внешне схожи никакой "схожести" не вижу. Ну ладно, одно правило понятно, набор простых полей можно заменять звездочнкой